# FitVid not working for iframes on particular theme install

Tags: theme-development, jquery, videos, responsive

I am using FitVid in my theme and all is well except for a specific site that was migrated from Drupal. FitVid works fine with objects and embeds but not iframes, and only on this particular site. The only difference I can find is that a random `<noscript>` is inserted after the iframe.

Here is an example of the non working iframe on the problematic site:
http://wp.alimomeni.net/project/animal-warmth-no-64/

And here is an example with a different database where no  shows up:
http://wpfolio.notlaura.com/project/pollen-from-hazelnut/

Why is FitVid not working for iframes that particular site install? I am concerned there is an issue with the database itself as the content was pretty messy after the initial migration and I haven't been able to replicate the issue anywhere else.

Any help greatly appreciated!

P.S. I have tried other responsive video plugins and my own jQuery to wrap the iframes.

Comment: Why is the `<noscript>` tag a problem?

Comment: Just a guess- it's the only difference I've found between the two sites. The main issue here is that the FitVid is not working for iframes on [this site](http://wp.alimomeni.net/project/animal-warmth-no-64/), but is okay with all other installs of the theme.

Comment: Both videos on that page work in FF, IE, Chrome, Opera, and Safari on Windows 7. One of them (top) does not work on FF on Debian-- I probably just don't have the right player installed. What OS/Browser are you using?

Comment: The videos work fine, but they are not resizing to full width e.g. [http://i.imgur.com/ouFEV7m.png](this one is good) vs. [http://i.imgur.com/fTrbRJV.png](the problem one) that is not wrapped by the div from FitVid

Comment: How are the videos inserted into your posts? Has the whole embed code been pasted into the content or is it just a link to the Vimeo page?

Comment: All of the embed content